# SUM value when another column value is DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering how I can SUM the values of a column based on another column's values being distinct like below. I tried the following two ways, each giving errors due to the aggregate function. I am trying to get NonDistinctTotals with the queries below.

```
SELECT SUM(InvoiceSaleAmt) AS NonDistinctTotals, SUM(case when count(*) over (partition by InvoiceNo) = 1 then InvoiceSaleAmt else 0 END) as DistinctTotals, SUM(CASE WHEN PaymentType= 'CASH' THEN CashTotal ELSE 0 END) AS CashTotal
FROM @InvoiceTable a
group by LocationId, InvoiceNo
```

> Error: Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate.

```
SELECT SUM(InvoiceSaleAmt) AS NonDistinctTotals, SUM(CASE WHEN InvoiceNoin (SELECT DISTINCT InvoiceNofrom @InvoiceTable) THEN InvoiceSaleAmt else 0 END) as DistinctTotals, SUM(CASE WHEN PaymentType= 'CASH' THEN CashTotal ELSE 0 END) AS CashTotal
FROM @InvoiceTable a
group by LocationId, InvoiceNo
```

> Error: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(InvoiceSaleAmt) AS NonDistinctTotals,
       SUM(case when cnt = 1 then InvoiceSaleAmt else 0 END) as DistinctTotals,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PaymentType = 'CASH' THEN CashTotal ELSE 0 END) AS CashTotal
FROM (SELECT it.*, COUNT(*) over (partition by InvoiceNo) as cnt
      FROM @InvoiceTable it
     ) it
GROUP BY LocationId, InvoiceNo
```